# Можно ли сделать, что бы Visual Studio при подключении библиотек копировала их в папку с проектом и не использовала GAC?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Можно ли сделать, что бы Visual Studio при подключении библиотек копировала их в папку с проектом и не использовала глобальный кеш сборок?

Comment: Хотите запускать на машине без установленного .Net или с какой целью?

Comment: @Monk, для удобства. Допустим я передаю проект другому юзеру, а у него может не быть библиотек нужной версии.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я делаю так:

1. Добавляю сборки явно в проект, как обычные файлы.
2. Выставляю у них признак копировать при сборке.
3. На них же устанавливаю референсы в проекте.

Итого, все сторонние сборки копируются в папку при сборке, у пользователей запускается.

Comment: +1, но что-то мне кажется, что первый пункт не нужен.

Comment: @VladD, а где их потом искать то? Раз они сторонние, то это либо NuGet, либо просто либы прямо в проекте. Учитывая, что ТС задает такие вопросы - лучше уж просто либы хранить.

Comment: Ну, по идее, либо они из nuget, либо просто лежат в каталоге с проектом в source control'е. Просто добавлять их в сам проект, кажется, лишний шаг.

Comment: @VladD, а, ну я их просто ещё как встраиваемые ресурсы делаю, чтобы в один файл упаковать. Аж задумался, нафига =)

Comment: А, тогда при старте их можно первым делом распаковать? А что, остроумно.

Comment: У нас здесь было несколько вопросов по поводу того, как влить все DLL-ки в один исполнимый файл. Возможно, там не хватает вашего ответа :)